# Preparing data for classification algorithm

Tags: r, algorithm, machine-learning, classification, cross-validation

I have to prepare and classify a dataset composed by 100 000 + lines and 105 variables and I'm looking for advices.(I'm using R)

basically, 
the set is full of dummy variables and missing values(44% of the full dataset).

and Idk what to do with the NAs, I'm split up between two ideas : 
I] 
1- eliminate every column that has more than 70% of mising values
2- Replace the missing values with mean or median in the remaining columns

II]
eliminate all the missing values

what do you think ?

is there something more I can do to prepare the data ? (except dealing with NAs)

Comment: This should be tagged with `r` if thats the language you are using

Comment: This is not an R question, it is a research methodology question about imputation of missing values. It's better suited for [CrossValidated](https://stats.stackexchange.com) than SO.

Answer (score 0):

The topic of imputation of missing values has a long history in the social sciences, going back at least as far as when I was a graduate student during the 1980s and had to explain to a professor of Political Science at Michigan State University why she couldn't replicate a factor analysis she had previously conducted because SPSS eliminated the *mean substitution of missing values* option from the factor analysis procedure.

There is a wide variety of research (and opinion) on how to handle missing data in statistical analyses. For example, in [Chapter 25](http://www.stat.columbia.edu/~gelman/arm/missing.pdf) of [Data Analysis Using Regression and Multilevel / Hierarchical Models](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/052168689X), Gelman and Hill describe multiple approaches for imputing one variable as well as multiple variables.

In order to select an imputation strategy for a particular data set, one must assess why the missing data are missing. Gelman & Hill review four major categories of "missingness mechanisms," including:

1. Missingness completely at random (probability of missingness is equal across all units / subjects)
2. Missingness at random (e.g. differing response rates across races)
3. Missingness that depends on unobserved predictors
4. Missingness that depends on the missing value itself (e.g. people earning more than $100,000 refuse to respond to income question)

Therefore, without analyzing the original poster's specific data set against the missingness mechanisms, specific guidance on which imputation technique to use is inappropriate. Additional research on missing data imputation may be found at [Strategies for Handling Missing Values](https://github.com/lgreski/datasciencectacontent/blob/master/markdown/gen-handlingMissingValues.md).

Comment: I will have a look at that , Thank you !